# Node 12 | Reference error: FinalizationRegistry is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, dreamhost

I am trying to host a Node.js (Express) app at DreamHost using shared unlimited plan. I was able to do most of the work. There is only one problem, DreamHost uses Passenger to run Node.js apps, and Passenger does not support Node 14+, so I have to stick with Node 12.

The Express project I was building is built on TypeScript and I used Node 16 to do all of the stuff (installing, running, etc.). When I build the TypeScript, it uses an NPM package `exit-free-leak` which uses `FinalizationRegistry`, hence requires Node v14+.

So after building the app, when I run the app.js with Node 12 it gives me the error that `FinalizationRegistry is not defined`. For now I am getting this error, but the `exit-free-leak` uses another Node 14+ function `WeakRef`.

How do I get around this issue while using Node 12? Is there any way to polyfill these functions or disable use of the package `exit-free-leak` using `tsconfig.json`, or maybe an even better solution?

Comment: _"I used Node 16 to do all of the stuff"_ - step one is: don't do that. If you're forced to use Node 12 in a production environment (and cannot change the production environment), use it in the dev environment too, so at least you find out about these things earlier. Step two would be downgrading the library to a version that has Node 12 support, or removing it if no such support exists.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer to "how do I get around this issue while using node v12" is probably: "you don't".

Node 12 [has been end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/nodejs) for 9 months; given how fast the JavaScript ecosystem moves in general, it's unlikely that libraries will keep supporting that version for very long anyway.

You'd be best off asking Dreamhost about Node 16 or 18 support, or move elsewhere if they can't provide you with up-to-date runtimes *that still get security updates*.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I modified my node version to 16 and it worked

Comment: But, according to the OP's question: "…Dreamhost uses passenger to run node js app, and passenger does not support node 14+, so I have to stick with node v12" As a result, upgrading to v16 doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the project folder and run below commands and try

npm install